# When i click save button data stores in database. when refresh using f5 data saves twice

Tags: sql-server

When i click save button data stores in database. when refresh using f5 data saves twice.
i used update panel, page response.redirect("samepage.aspx") but no use
aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddCust.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddCust" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<div>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomername" runat="server"  >
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter The name" ControlToValidate="txtCustomername" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcustomer" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlcustomer_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

aspx code

asxcs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using odonovanTableAdapters;

public partial class AddCust : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customerdropdown();

    }
```

code

```
public void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ButtonSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return validate()");
    string name = txtCustomername.Text;

    string company = txtCompany.Text;
if (company == "")
{
    company = "0";
}
string address = txtaddress.Text;
if (address == "")
{
    address = "0";
}

long phonenumber = Convert.ToInt64(txtPhonenumber.Text);

string otherdetails = txtOtherDetails.Text;
if (otherdetails == "")
{
    otherdetails = "0";
}
```

code

```
tblCustomerdetailsTableAdapter tadaptor = new tblCustomerdetailsTableAdapter();
tadaptor.Insert(name, company, address, phonenumber, otherdetails);
//  Response.Write("<script>alert('saved successfully')</script>");
```

}

code

```
   protected void customerdropdown()
        {
            //fill broker ddl
            ddlcustomer.DataSource = DropDowns.ddlcustomers();
            ddlcustomer.DataValueField = "CustomerName";
            ddlcustomer.DataTextField = "CustomerName";
            ddlcustomer.DataBind();
            ddlcustomer.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select --");
        }
```

code

```
    protected void ddlcustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        string customername = ddlcustomer.SelectedValue;
        spddlcustselectedvalueTableAdapter cadaptor = new spddlcustselectedvalueTableAdapter();
        odonovan.spddlcustselectedvalueDataTable ctable = cadaptor.GetData(customername);
        txtCustomername.Text = ctable.Rows[0][1].ToString();


    }
}
```

Comment: You're saving on GET rather than POST. Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply redirect user to the same page once record is saved successfully to prevent repeating the same action (insert) again.

Pass some token in Querystring so that you can display success message to user.